# How can I calculate the center of an NSButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsbutton

I'm not sure how to find the center of my button:

```
spinner = [[EKActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([followButton bounds].origin.x/2, [followButton bounds].origin.y/2, 16, 16)];
```

Dividing the frame.x and frame.y does not do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to do:

```
CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX([followButton frame]), CGRectGetMidY([followButton frame]), 16, 16)
```

Alternatively, the correct formula is:

```
CGRect frame;
CGPoint center;
frame = [view frame];
center.x = frame.origin.x + (frame.size.width / 2);
center.y = frame.origin.y + (frame.size.height / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

```
CGRectMake(NSMidX([followButton frame], NSMidY([followButton frame]), 16, 16)
```

Using the bounds will return (0,0) for the origin, only taking into account the size of the button. Using the frame will provide the origin as well.

Edit: sorry, my code is a bastardized cocoa/core graphics hybrid.